# Simple HTML Dom - Replace Relative Links

Tags: php, foreach

I am using the simple_html_dom libary to scrape a menu of an external site.

This works fine, but the links are all relative and return /about/contact rather then mydomain.com/about/contact.

How is the best way to replace these instances within my loop? Ex:

```
$html_out = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com/'); 
if ( $html_out ) {
    foreach($html_out->find('#menu-position-wrapper') as $article) {
    echo $article;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$html_out = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com/'); 
if ( $html_out ) {
    foreach($html_out->find('#menu-position-wrapper') as $article) {
      foreach ($article->find('a[href]') as $a) {
        $href = $a->href;
        $a->href = 'http://www.domain.com'.$href;
  }    
 }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that looks a little better then what I had - I'll give it a test. Thanks.

Comment: @David.J If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!

Comment: Sure, I am just testing it